# English translation of von Neumann's "Zur Theorie der Gesellschaftsspiele", 1928

Tags: game-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german

Some colleagues and I are reading various classic papers. We would like to read von Neumann's "Zur Theorie der Gesellschaftsspiele", 1928, but do not read German. Do you know of an English translation, or perhaps another paper/book chapter by von Neumann with similar content?

The whole of "Theory of Games and Economic Behaviour" is too much for this reading group, but if one or two chapters contain the same content that would work.

Comment: Zur Theorie der Gesellschaftsspiele (not Zur theorie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little late since this question is now almost four years old. However, the translated version is Von Neumann J (1959) On the theory of games of strategy. Contributions to the Theory of Games 4:13–42

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9lSVFzsTGWsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA13&dq=On%20the%20theory%20of%20games%20of%20strategy&ots=P1NEdMN_pE&sig=Wq5pmHMqXXwJTMb1GvsGpFicFQ8#v=onepage&q=On%20the%20theory%20of%20games%20of%20strategy&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

An available (at least to me at the current time) [link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ey328yu/classics/vonNeumann.pdf) for the English verison titled *On the theory of games of strategy*, translated by Sonya Bargmmann.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Games_and_Economic_Behavior), the book **Theory of Games and Economic Behaviour** (1944) written by Von Neumann and Morgenstern is based on the research published in *Zur Theorie der Gesellschaftsspiele*.

I think this is the closest you can get if you don't know any German, since there does not seem to be a translation of the original text.

Comment: Thank you, although this is too long for us to read. Can you recommend a chapter or two that contain the relevant content?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't since I haven't read it myself. My game theory course was in German, so we used German books/articles. Are you just interested in learning some basic game theory in general or do you absolutely want to read about it from Von Neumann?

Comment: We are reading "classic papers", so we would like something by von Neumann or similar. If we can't find it will look at Nash instead.